# grub-update and "/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem"

Tags: linux, macos, multi-boot, grub2, hfs+

I've got a Debian 7 Wheezy (stable release) and my GRUB suddenly refuses to see one of my partitions. It is an OS X HFS+ partition on the GPT disk.

This behavior was introduced in the month or so and it is either caused by a routine update either of Debian or OS X. The error is `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem`.

Here is a excerpt of the output:

```
user@wheezy:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Device or resource busy
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda3
Found Debian GNU/Linux (7.8) on /dev/mapper/altwheezy_vg-main_lv
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Found Debian GNU/Linux (7.8) on /dev/mapper/altwheezy_vg-main_lv_snapshot
done
user@wheezy:~$
```

As you can see, there is also a `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem` error being printed multiple times.

I have two Debian Wheezy on the computer and I tried both of them. To no avail. I've even tried GRUB from the *testing* repository, but the error is still here.

I wondered if my Linux suddenly failed to see GPT HFS+ partition or its type, but it is too not the case, since I've got all the necessary packages installed (`hfsplus`, `hfsprogs`, `hfsutils`), `gparted` sees it, `gdisk` sees it and the filesystem type is right, but `grub` cannot see it.

On the OS X side, I've checked the partition from the OS X itself with Disk Utility and it didn't reported anything wrong.

Someone please direct me what should I check to determine the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured it out.

It is absolutely unnecessary to have GRUB to see all of file systems. You can just instruct GRUB to bypass all operations and to [chain load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_loading#Chain_loading_in_boot_manager_programs) the next bootloader (Chameleon in my case). So I ended up with this in my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "OS X" --class macosx --class os {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod hfsplus
        set root='(hd2)'
        chainloader +1
}
```